# Sys Admin lost access to community

Tags: community, user-management

When I configured community on my Org I removed System Admin (me) profile from Community Members (see the screenshot 1)

[image: community members]

So neither System Admin not anybody else can manage, modify or delete this community

[image: inaccessible community]

How to get access to community back?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Below the link how to add system admin (yourself) to community to be able to manage it.

https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?urlname=How-do-I-add-myself-as-a-member-of-a-Community-if-the-Manage-Link-is-missing&language=en_US

Comment: I know this is an older thread, but thanks so much for posting this.  I deleted my profile from the members list, not knowing I'd lose access to configuring the community, and this article saved me.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Hi Try to get in touch with salesforce support team. They are the omnly one seems like will be able to help.

call them on 1 (800) 667-6389 here is there number. or contact them through email on using this link https://www.salesforce.com/form/contact/contactme.jsp

Answer (score 2):

If you have local copy of the project in sfdx including "[networks](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_network.htm)" - it's simpler to restore access by redeploying 1 file. Cleaner than this official help article with url hacking...

Make sure your package.xml contains

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>Network</name>
    </types>
    <version>51.0</version>
</Package>
```

And then the file will be something like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Network xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <!-- bla bla bla -->
    <gatherCustomerSentimentData>false</gatherCustomerSentimentData>
    <lockoutTemplate>Community/CommunityUserLocked</lockoutTemplate>
    
    <networkMemberGroups>
        <permissionSet>Feature1Access</permissionSet>
        <permissionSet>Feature2Access</permissionSet>
        <profile>admin</profile>                    <!-- System Administrator access here -->
        <profile>secret client name user</profile>
    </networkMemberGroups>
    
    <!-- bla bla bla -->
    <picassoSite>Client_Portal1</picassoSite>
    <!-- bla bla bla -->
</Network>
```